# COM+ Unspecified error , -2147467259

Tags: vbscript, sybase, com+

I have an old application, which needs to be migrated and it need to be setup under 
Windows 2000.
The web page is ASP and it calls up the COM+. The COM+ will call the udl file and connect db through DataDirect.

When the COM+ open connection, it hang and throw `'Unspecified Error:-2147467259'`

```
conDB.Open "File Name=E:\test.udl"  //throw exception
```

the logic flow is:

```
ASP -> COM+ -> udl(DataDirect Connect ADO 2.7 : DataDirect Sybase ADO Provider driver) -> database
```

Information:

- OS: Windows 2000
- Sybase SDK 12.5.1
- MDAC version 2.7
- DataDirect Connect ADO 2.7, use DataDirect Sybase ADO Provider
  driver.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
conDB.Open "File Name=E:\test.udl"
```

Comment: Sorry, it just my typo mistake. The "File Name" is included in my connection string. Anyway, thanks. :)